# How do I fix pycharm?

Tags: python3, pycharm

I reinstalled Ubuntu recently, and everything went fine until I tried to install PyCharm.
It worked properly on my past install, and I tried installing it with the Ubuntu Store and the tarball file from the official website.

When I start the program it gives me
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZDbg.png)

The problem is that i cannot run the programs in pycharm. I can still edit them although.

[It looks like a module error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yoq0m.png) but i'm not sure how to fix it.
[(I also found a file called brokenplugins.db)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cbKP.png)

My ubuntu version is 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Comment: Did you give pycharm a correct path to the python interpreter?

Comment: Configure [virtual environment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html).